# Why my recursive function failed in looping?

Tags: java, android, recursion

I've implemented a recursive funcion in Java. The function always fail after x number of loops. I can't find the reason why it fails. I debugged it step by step but when it fails, I  Don't have a clue why. Can I get help? Code snippets

```
public void Eight_ConnectedComponent_Spreading_Recursion(int r, int c){
    Size s = ROI_GRAY.size();
    //Make 8 points of neighbours
    Vector<Point> filldata = new Vector<Point>(); 
    byte[] data = new byte[1]; 
    for(int row = -1; row < 2; row++){
        for(int col = -1; col < 2; col++){
            if((r+row >= 0 && r+row < s.height) && (c+col >= 0 && c+col < s.width))
            {
                ROI_GRAY.get(r+row, c+col, data);
                if(data[0] == WHITE)
                    filldata.add(new Point( r+row, c+col));
            }
        }
    }
    if(filldata.size() > 0){
        for (int row = 0; row < filldata.size() ; row++ ) { 
            ROI_GRAY.put((int)filldata.get(row).x, (int)filldata.get(row).y, (byte)BLACK);
        }
        while(filldata.size() > 0) {    
            if((int)filldata.get(0).x != r && (int)filldata.get(0).y != c)
                Eight_ConnectedComponent_Spreading_Recursion((int)filldata.get(0).x, (int)filldata.get(0).y);
            filldata.remove(0);
        }


    }
    filldata.trimToSize();  //

    return;
}
```

Comment: If your application is crashing, please post your LogCat to findout where its failed.

Comment: What is the error that causes it to fail?

Comment: add logs, also post an example run - input, expected output and failure notification (or what happens when error happen)

Comment: Don't use a `Vector`, use a `List`. This is 2014, not 1994...

Comment: Hi, what class is ROI_GRAY?

Comment: ROI_GRAY is a OpenCV's matrix for holding image pixel values. It is a public data for that class.

Comment: @fge; u mean Vector can be problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please port your LogCat messages.

When you say "always fail after x number of loops" that makes me think you may be encountering a StackOverflowError due to too many levels of recursion. That usually means that your end-condition isn't working as expected.

Comment: Thks that make sense. Let me check

Comment: Was that the cause of the problem? If you've found an answer, please post it in order to help others with similar problems. If any of the community posted answers answered your question or materially helped you solve it, please mark it as accepted.